# Unbroken line in preview text causes whole post block to side scroll

Tags: bug, questions, design

I saw the following result [in a filter I have setup](https://stackexchange.com/filters/206781/neural-genetic), where one of the post summary previews contains a long unbroken line of text.

This causes the entire post block itself to show a horizontal side scroll as opposed to just the preview text area.

[image: text listing summary]

Seems like there is a really long connected string that doesn't allow it to be cut off!

Comment: Does not look like an overflow because it's still inside the boundary. Or did you crop the side of the image?

Comment: @random that question is specifically about titles and the answer is "don't allow long unbroken titles". I don't think that's obviously the same for the body of a question.

Comment: The original version of this report was "it looks odd" but had no details about what was actually odd that it wasn't the same issue as something else odd

Answer (score 2):

A fairly simple CSS solution to this problem would be:

```css
#question-list .question { word-wrap: break-word }
```

This would (in most cases, at least) eliminate the need for scroll bars entirely, producing something like the following output (demonstrated by artificially inserting a very long word into the question summary) instead:

> [image: screenshot]

---

Alternatively, it would be possible to move the scrollbar so that it wouldn't include the answer count on the left, e.g. with the following CSS rule:

```css
#question-list .question { overflow: auto }
```

which would look something like this:

> [image: screenshot]

However, IMO this seems unnecessary.  With the addition of the `word-wrap: break-word` style, the current overflow styling should be quite adequate to catch any possible remaining cases where the content of the answer summary would still threaten to overflow into the sidebar.